# How does OpenZeppelin Governance library prevents double voting using ERC20Votes?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin, dao, governance

What prevents a user from voting and transferring all their tokens to a new address and vote again using OpenZeppelin's on-chain governance library and ERC20Votes contract?

Locking up tokens may prevent users from transferring votes until the proposal is passed or failed, but locking tokens may disincentivize participation. Is there a better way to approach this potential vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

ERC20Votes contract has a function that you can use to prevent users from voting and transferring all their tokens to a new address (transferring the voting power)

```
function getPastVotes(address account, uint256 blockNumber) 
        public view virtual override returns (uint256) {        
    require(blockNumber < block.number, "ERC20Votes: block not yet mined");
    return _checkpointsLookup(_checkpoints[account], blockNumber);
}
```

**Retrieve the number of votes for `account` at the end of `blockNumber`**

as you can see, it uses a specific block number in order to check the user's voing power at that point